# How to pass time_range params to FB api V2.8

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to pass some parameters to an adset in FB api.
I am using the following code

```
FB.api('adsetId',params,callback(response));
```

And i have defined my params as following:

```
var params = {
      fields: ['name',
        'insights.date_preset(last_90_days).time_increment(1){spend,impressions,date_start,date_stop,cpc,ctr,cpm}',
        {time_range:{'since':'2016-09-11','until':'2016-11-11'}}
      ],

    };
```

I get the error:

> code:100 fbtrace_id : "D5Y2dSU+BVM" message : "(#100) Tried accessing
>   nonexisting field (Array) on node type (AdCampaign)" type :
>   "OAuthException"
>   Then i tried changing the params as following:

```
var params = {
      fields: ['name',
        'insights.date_preset(last_90_days).time_increment(1){spend,impressions,date_start,date_stop,cpc,ctr,cpm}'],
      time_range:{'since':'2016-09-11','until':'2016-11-11'}
    };
```

But the now time_range has not effect at all in the call of FB api. Can anyone help me to figure out how can i pass the parameters using FB api? I am using FB JS SDK.

Comment: anyone want to help me?